# Resolving deadlock - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I am getting a deadlock between these 2 queries from 2 separate stored procedures:

1.

```
UPDATE ord
SET
    [Num] = @Num,
    [Ref] = @Re,
    [Date] = @Date
FROM [Order] ord
INNER JOIN [Orders_Open] oo ON oo.Id = ord.ID
```

2.

```
    UPDATE oo
    SET oo.Name = i.Name,
    oo.Email = i.Email,
    oo.PostCode = i.PostCode,
    FROM Item_Order i 
    INNER JOIN [Orders_Open] oo ON oo.ID = i.ID
```

What is the best way to tackle preventing a deadlock from happening? I have looked into using holdlock to prevent a deadlock before it happens:

e.g.

```
    UPDATE oo WITH (HOLDLOCK)
    SET oo.Name = i.Name,
    oo.Email = i.Email,
    oo.PostCode = i.PostCode,
    FROM Item_Order i 
    INNER JOIN [Orders_Open] oo ON oo.ID = i.ID
```

Would this work? Or can anyone else give advice on what else i could try?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any previous operations on the same transaction in each SP?

Comment: More than 1 update firing at the same time, hitting the same source?

Comment: @EzLo nope, just a select statement. The transactions are also implicit. Would it resolve any issues by making them explicit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is that when the UPDATES are firing, update 1 is joining in your oo table which is also being updated - have you tried simply adding a nolock to the UPDATE 1 script that follows INNER JOIN [Orders_Open] oo WITH (NOLOCK) ?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, if you mean autocommit (default behavior where each statement is an individual transaction), I wouldn't expect an explict transaction to make a different. Implicit transactions start a transaction when updates are performed but do not commit the transaction automatically.

Comment: How do `[Order]` from first query and `Item_Order` from second are related?

Comment: @AlexYu do you mean what relation do they have?

Comment: `[Order]` and `Item_Order`: a) different tables and totally unrelated, b) different tables with relation thru constraint(s), c) one of them is view of another, d) synonyms, e) name of one of them is mistyped

Comment: @AlexYu b) different tables with relation thru constraint(s)

Comment: @jimmy8ball what if NOLOCK isnt an option because of the potential for dirty reads?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the foreign keys? If not, the join need to scan more rows when reading which rows to update

Answer (score 0):

You can,t update same record simultaneously because **data integrity** must be kept in every transaction.

> data integrity refers to the **accuracy** and **consistency** of data
>   stored in a database, data warehouse, data mart or other construct.

You can use one transaction block for both of query to prevent deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to tune both for performance, so its less likely they will both will be running at the same moment.